# How to make a border around Jbutton thicker?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have the following JButton on the GUI interface I'm building.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/MucqvGj.png]

I want to make the border around the button more thicker so it will stand out from the background. Is it possible to do this in Java?

Comment: What PLAF is used for that screen-shot?  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Its just the default PLAF...

Comment: Maybe a `CompoundBorder`? The outer would be an `EmptyBorder` and the inner a `LineBorder`.

Comment: Is this a bad question? Because I searched the website first and I couldnt find a similar question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use a `LineBorder`

```
JButton btn = ...;
btn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4));
```

Take a look at [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more details and ideas

**Updating the border state based on the model state**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        protected static final Border NORMAL_BORDER = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4);
        protected static final Border ROLLOVER_BORDER = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 4);

        public TestPane() {

            JButton btn = new JButton("Click me!");
            btn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            btn.setBorder(NORMAL_BORDER);
            btn.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    if (btn.getModel().isRollover()) {
                        btn.setBorder(ROLLOVER_BORDER);
                    } else {
                        btn.setBorder(NORMAL_BORDER);
                    }
                }
            });

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(btn);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but one problem...It is losing the Hover state if I set the border using this method...Anyway to fix this?

Comment: You could listen the `ButtonModel` and update the `Border` when the model `isRollover` is `true`...

Comment: Thank you...you are always very kind and helpful

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Border` first -

```
Border border = new LineBorder(Color.WHITE, 13);
```

Then create a `JButton` and set the `Border` -

```
JButton button = new JButton("Button Name");
button.setBorder(border);
```

Hope it will Help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ohh! it just like a saying at the end of mail. Isn't a good practice? (I'm not sure, just asking) Then I will remove it.

Comment: *"Isn't a good practice?"*  Well, used in a context where you are not offering thanks to someone for a specific action, it is nonsense.  *"..like a saying at the end of mail."*  'Please RSVP' is a logical end to a communication for which we expect a reply.  Some might say that adding 'Thanks a lot' at the end of a communication means or implies the same thing, but I disagree on that.